# What term do I use to distingush between a data visualisation graph and a nodes and edges graph?

Tags: graph-theory

When googling, I have a problem distingishing my searches between a data visualation graphs (eg. scatter plots, bar charts etc), and node and edge graphs.

The term 'directed graph' can be used, but not all node and edge graphs are directed.

Is there specific terms I can use to distinguish the two?

Comment: add the word vertex to your search.

Comment: Is your goal to filter out results that are also charts (like the scatter plots, bar charts, etc)? or do you want to filter out the $G=(V,E)$ graphs?

Comment: I want to filter out results. Essentially I'm trying to google 'graph (G = (V,E)) visualisation library javascript'

Comment: For googlers, it's very annoying that graph theorists decided to use everyday English words for so many of their terms, rather than more easily searchable ones such as "syzygy".